# Condition for while loop doesn't work in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I want the loop to repeat if the number is not equal to 0 and rest%2 is equal to 1 or -1. But this does not seem to work:

```
while (number != 0 && rest%2 == 1 || rest%2 == -1)
```

How do I have to write the code so it works?

Comment: Whenever you see AND and OR used flatly with multiple conditions, you know you need to use parentheses somewhere.

Comment: What are `number` and `rest`? The condition would work with the correct values so we need to know how those values come to be.

Comment: just use `while loop` and put the conditions inside the `loop` with `if statement`

Comment: `a && (b || c)` != `(a && b) || c`.  The answers below demonstrate the confusion nicely, you need to pick the relevant option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
while (number != 0 && (rest%2 == 1 || rest%2 == -1))
```

Comment: So simple, thank you, I am pretty new to java

Answer (score 3):

While it's good to learn about operator precedence, your expression can be reduced:

```
while (number != 0 && rest%2 != 0)
```

Put another way, `n % 2` is 0 for positive and negative even numbers and something not even must be odd (which is what you are testing).

Comment: `rest%2 != 0` covers `number != 0`, as well. Even more reducible!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Java operator precedence here https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

If I understand correctly you want to enter the loop in two cases:

- `number != 0 && rest%2 == 1`

**OR**

- `rest%2 == -1`

If that's true consider using parentheses:

```
while ((number != 0 && rest%2 == 1) || rest%2 == -1)
```